# Trouble with object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am geting a null pointer exception when i try to run this method, the goal is to populate the booklist object array but not over 3 objects. The error occurs when i set booklist[0] = b

```
private Book [] booklist;
public boolean borrowBook(Book b)
{
    if(booklist == null)
    {
        booklist[0] = b;
        System.out.println(this.name+" has successfully borrowed "+b);
        return true;
    }
    if(booklist.length < 3)
    {
        booklist[booklist.length] = b;
        System.out.println(this.name+" has successfully borrowed "+b);
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println(this.name+" has reached the borrowing limit! Return those books "+this.name);
    return false;
```

Comment: You need to initialize `booklist`.

Comment: I am not that knowledgeable with object arrays, can i initialize it and have my borrowBook method work the way it is?

Comment: of course if `booklist == null` you cannot access `booklist[0]`

Comment: default datatype is null for objects

Comment: what would i put in place of booklist[0] = b then

Comment: U need to Initialize the book list first with out that u wont be able to add any element that will be having null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
private Book [] booklist;

public boolean borrowBook(Book b) {
    if (booklist == null) {
        booklist = new Book[3];
        booklist[0] = b;
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < booklist.length; i++) {
        if (booklist[i] == null) {
            booklist[i] = b;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book caller = new Book();
    System.out.println(caller.borrowBook(new Book()));
    System.out.println(caller.borrowBook(new Book()));
    System.out.println(caller.borrowBook(new Book()));
    System.out.println(caller.borrowBook(new Book()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! , Other answers were all right , but my teacher expects me to use just a normal array for this project. Thanks everyone , and thank you wittakarn

Answer (score 4):

You need `ArrayList` instead of `array`

```
ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();

public boolean borrowBook(Book b){
    if(booklist.size() == 0){
        booklist.add(b);
        System.out.println(this.name+" has successfully borrowed "+b);
        return true;
    }
    if(booklist.size() < 3){ //I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here
        booklist.add(booklist.size(), b);
        System.out.println(this.name+" has successfully borrowed "+b);
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println(this.name+" has reached the borrowing limit! Return those books "+this.name);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, @August said.
Before line `booklist[0] = b;`

You must initial by using `booklist = new Book[3];`

Comment: Would my method still work at not letting it store more than 3 books into this array?

Comment: how can i check how many non-null objects are in booklist. By initializing it to length 3 , `if(booklist.length < 3)` will not work. what way can i check

Comment: I post my new answer, you can entertain. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are not dynamically sized, it's possible to write a method to do it. For example,

```
private static Book[] addBook(Book[] arr, Book b) {
    int newLen = (arr == null ? 1 : arr.length + 1);
    Book[] dest = new Book[newLen];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, dest, 0, arr == null ? 0 : arr.length);
    dest[newLen - 1] = b;
    return dest;
}
```

Then you could use it with something like

```
public boolean borrowBook(Book b) {
    if (booklist == null || booklist.length < 3) {
        booklist = addBook(booklist, b);
        System.out.println(this.name + " has successfully borrowed " + b);
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println(this.name + " has reached the borrowing limit! "
            + "Return those books " + this.name);
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just allocate an array of size `n` or use a collection like an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing `booklist` will fix the `NullPointerException`, but your method's logic will still be flawed. It appears that you want to *append* a new book to the array of books checked out, whereas your method will only set the last element in the array.

To fix this, you could use a counter that stores the index of the last book inserted. Or, I suggest using a growable array such as [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which supports appending new elements with [`ArrayList#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)).